# RDP from Ubuntu to Windows Server 2012 from WAN

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I'm having a problem when trying to connect to our RDP server from outside the LAN.

I have a .rdp file and I have imported it to Remmina 1.2.31.3 . Everything works fine when I'm connecting to the server from LAN, but if I try to connect from WAN, I get this error message

Connection to RDP server x.x.x.x failed
I have tried to change security types to "RDP,NLA,TLS,Negotiate", none of them worked.

If I write telnet "servername.domain" 3389, it says "Connected"

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Unless your server has a NAT (on whatever your edge device is - firewall/router) to give it a public presence you won't be able to connect to it publicly short of using something else (instead of RDP) such as TeamViewer or similar.

Comment: Yes we have NAT enabled on RDP server. But it suits only for Ubuntu? Because from MAC os and Windows users are able to connect

Comment: @MartynasŠavelis You have a public IP assigned (dedicated to) the RDP server, not a shared global NAT (really PAT)?

Comment: sorry, my bad, i was thinking about NLA not NAT.. So there are no possibility to connect from Ubuntu to windows server outside the LAN?

Comment: @MartynasŠavelis Not without a public IP assigned to it (NAT) or a PAT to direct a specific port to a specific target.  You will have to use something else like TeamViewer (which is free for personal and home use).